# Hide div with JS select box based on one of the Div's JSON values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need help getting my Javascript to work for a select dropdown that will hide a div based on a value of it's data in JSON. I have a page/laravel blade that loads furniture groups by using foreach loops and contains them in a div called `.group-container`. This is all done using a controller that builds our order form into a variable called `$orderFormData`, and then builds out the groups and individual products from there.

Here's the main basic structure, so you have an idea:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
<div class="group-container">
        <h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;">{{ $pgroup->group_name }} - {{ $pgroup->group_code }}</h3>
        <p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" >{!! html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}</p> <!--Group Description-->

            @foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)

            //table of rows for info

                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
@endforeach
```

So, I want 2 values in my dropdown to show/hide a `.group-container` if it has a certain value of 1 or 0, depending on the selection.

The dropdown has options for `popularity and recently ordered`. So if the user chooses popularity, I need it to map to `pgroups->topseller` and if that has a value of 1 show it, if it has a value of 0 hide it. Same for recently ordered, but I want that to map to `$pgroups->reorder`.

Here's a screenshot of the JSON data of `$orderFormData` when I dump it:

[image]

So you can see the structure is $orderFormData->pgroups->topseller/reorder

Here's the Search bar:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <div>
     <span style="color:#fff;"><strong>Sort by:</strong></span>
       <select id="filterText" class="uk-text-muted" style="margin-top:10px; width:33%; height:30px; font-size: 16px;" >
         <option id="allitems" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" selected data-default value="" selected data-default>All Items</option>
         <option id="popular" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="popularity" >Popularity</option>
         <option id="recent" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="recently_ordered">Recently Ordered </option>
       </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var topsellers = "<?php echo $pgroups->topseller; ?>";
var reorder    = "<?php echo $pgroups->reorder; ?>";
//console.log( topsellers );
$('#filterText').on('change', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();

  if (currentVal == 'popularity' && topsellers == "1" || currentVal == 'recently_ordered' && reorder == "1") {

    $(".groupcontainer").show();
   } else {
    $(".groupcontainer").hide();
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm thinking/hoping I'm just declaring something wrong but JS and JSON are not my wheelhouse. I just need to make sure everything's mapped correctly so that I can show/hide a div based on those values and the dropdown selection. Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, the variables `topsellers` and `reorder` are assigned whatever values is output by the `<?php echo>` command. From your comments, those values are `false` or `true`.

Therefore you simply need to match your JS equality check with those values :

```
$('#filterText').on('change', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();

  if (currentVal == 'popularity' && topsellers == "true" || currentVal == 'recently_ordered' && reorder == "true") {

    $(".groupcontainer").show();
   } else {
    $(".groupcontainer").hide();
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Oups, I didn't see the `<?php>` tags.. can you tell us what the console.log( topsellers ); outputs ?

Comment: It output false for the first group because it has a topseller value of 0. So if I expand all the groups in that json object from the screenshot, some have 1 or 0 for either of those values

Comment: Basically, I know now that the JSON object has the values, I just need to make sure I'm declaring the variables right

Comment: If it outputs false, shouldn't your test `topseller == "1"` says `!topseller`, or `topseller === false`?

Comment: Or `topseller === "false"` it that's actually a string?

Comment: I was thinking it would need to match the value of the JSON object, so I wasn't sure which way it should be done actually

Comment: As far as I can tell, here, you're reading your JSON in your PHP code, not in javascript, due to the `<php>` tags. Therefore your JS code would need to match whatever is output by the PHP evaluator.

Comment: ok well when I put a php dump for $orderFormData, it shows those values having 1 or 0, not as a string. SO would your answer above still work for this? And if so, How would I need to alter those two incomplete lines of JS?

Comment: I've edited my answer now that I understand the issue better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159063/discussion-between-metoule-and-tom-n).